# Default RStudio server user with H2O on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, rstudio, h2o

I am trying to use the RStudio server installation that comes with H2O, following instructions for bringing it up on EC2 [here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-lambert/5/docs-website/deployment/ec2_tutorial_cli.html). All of this completes successfully, and I get RStudio working on port 8787, however, I don't know what the default logon credentials are. Are there any? Will have to log into the EC2 instance and configure a user manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation that you are referencing is actually for an older version of H2O. You can reference our new documentation here: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-simons/7/docs-website/h2o-docs/index.html#%E2%80%A6%20On%20EC2%20and%20S3

This should cover the questions that you have. If not, please let me know!

Comment: you should paste the content which answers the question.